# Error with installation apache2 held packets

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2

I try to install install **apache2**, but receive an error

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

apache2 : Depend: apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7) 
                  apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7)
                  apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7)
                  apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7)
          Depend: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7) but 2.2.22-6ubuntu5.1 will be installed

You have held packagets
```

Please, help me, how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get update 
dpkg -a --configure
apt-get install -y apache2
apt-get install -f
```

Execute this. Give output if it doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7) but it is not going to be installed or
                    apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2.2-common (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7) but it is not going to be installed